# vue @click not changing class

Tags: vue.js, styles

sorry I'm still new to reactive vue models and updating I'm trying to draw a line through an input element if a box is checked.

so far I have this setup:

```
 data: {
      selected: null,
      checked: null,
      list: [
        {
          id: 0,
          category: 'Bakery',
          food: ['bread','muffins','pie']
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          category: 'Fruits',
          food: ['apple','bananna','orange']
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          category: 'Diary',
          food: ['cheese','milk','yogurt']
        }
      ],
      isHidden: true, 
      form: {},
    },
```

my html is as follows (this is a single page app)

```
<li v-for="food in item.food" class="list-group-item">
                    <input :class="{marked:food == checked}" @click="checked = food" type="checkbox"> {{ food }}</input>
                </li>
```

this is the css i'm trying to implement

```
.marked{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to my @click to make it work but so far nothing happens and the class is not applied. Can someone give me tips?

Answer (score 0):

An `<input>` element can't have content.

So you've got this structure:

```html
<input>{{ food }}</input>
```

But that's misleading as the `<input>` tag will be closed automatically. What you'll end up with will actually be some text next to a checkbox, not inside it.

You probably want something similar to this:

```html
<label :class="{marked: food === checked}" @click="checked = food">
  <input type="checkbox"> {{ food }}
</label>
```

There are some other problems involving deselection and multiple selections. I've tried to fix those in the example below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    checked: [],

    list: [
      {
        id: 0,
        category: 'Bakery',
        food: ['bread','muffins','pie']
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        category: 'Fruits',
        food: ['apple','bananna','orange']
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        category: 'Diary',
        food: ['cheese','milk','yogurt']
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.marked{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="item in list">
    <li v-for="food in item.food" class="list-group-item">
      <label :class="{marked: checked.includes(food)}">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" :value="food">{{ food }}
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```